# 2FA for Microsoft AD, disable old device authenticator

Tags: azure, active-directory, two-factor-authentication

I have a MS environment where we use MS AD to connect our users to a remote desktop. For that we use the MS 2FA authenticator app, so users connect with username&password and approve the log-in by accepting the authenticator pop-up on their phone. I have a demo account which should be used by a different person every week. So what I do to "clean the account":

- on https://admin.microsoft.com/ , change the password of the account to a new password of my choosing
- on https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/UserManagement/MultifactorVerification.aspx , I check the following options in User settings:

[x] Require selected users to provide contact methods again

[x] Delete all existing app passwords generated by the selected users

[ ] Restore multi-factor authentication on all remembered devices

- next, I go to portal.azure.com and go for "Dashboard > Users - All users > Demo3 Account - Authentication methods" , remove the phone number and also there click the Require Re-register MFA and Revoke MFA sesssions.

When the new user of the demo account starts, he/she goes to microsoftonline.com , scans the QR code and can log in all fine to the demo account with the password and 2FA app. The issues I have:

1. the main issue is that the old user of that demo account keeps on getting the pop-up from the authenticator app every time the new person wants to log in. *I seem not able to remove the old device/app as an admin. Does someone know how to do that?*
2. I have no overview of *how many apps/phones can approve the 2FA request* of that demo account, is there a way to see that? (And maybe there disable just 1 device.)

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the authentication app from https://aka.ms/mfasetup

This will answer both your questions, as within this URL you can see all mobile apps linked to the account.

Comment: Thanks for that reply. It was what I was fearing for: I have to log into the individual demo account in order to remove a device. There is no way for me as an admin to remove devices for multiple accounts, or did I miss something?